# Carnival Game Odds: Thunderbolt

Tags: probability, permutations

I came across an interesting carnival game called Thunderbolt that involves 36 tiles numbered 1, 2, ..., 36. The game goes like this.

- A participant chooses 18 tiles out of the 36 tiles randomly shuffled. Each tile has a back face so participants won't know what numbers they pick.
- There is a 6x6 board that is written 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the first row, and 7,8,9,10,11,12 on the second, and so on until 31,32,33,34,35,36.
- The participant then uncovers his 18 tiles and places them on the board corresponding to each tile number, i.e. tile #1 is placed on 1 on the board.
- The participant wins when an entire row or column is filled by tiles. eg. 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 1,7,13,19,25,31. More points are given for additional rows/columns. Diagonals don't count.

By the time the participant chooses his 18 tiles, the game is nothing more than just discovering if he has won by placing the tiles on the board. I am interested in the probability of getting at least one row or column filled in this game.

Here's what I know
 - there are 12 possible unique rows and columns combined to win a point.
 - but instead of thinking in terms of rows and columns, I thought it might be more useful to think numerically of winning combinations and the probability of drawing them, i.e.

- 1,2,3,4,5,6.
- 7,8,9,10,11,12
- 13,14,15,16,17,18
  ...
  and I find that for each combo, the probability of drawing that is ($\frac{1}{36}$)($\frac{1}{35}$)($\frac{1}{34}$)($\frac{1}{33}$)($\frac{1}{32}$)($\frac{1}{31}$) multiplied by a P or C which I can't figure out at this point...

Answer (score 2):

The probability to get a specific row, say the top one, is $\frac {{6 \choose 6}{30 \choose 12}}{36 \choose 18}\approx 0.00953$  We might think we could multiply that by $12$ to get the chance to get any row, which would give a winning probability of about $11.4\%$, but we would be counting cases where we have two complete rows twice.  This is where [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) comes in.  There are $30$ ways to get two parallel rows, with each one giving $\frac {24 \choose 6}{36\choose 18}\approx 0.000015$ and $36$ ways to get two perpendicular rows with each giving a chance of $\frac {25 \choose 7}{36 \choose 18} \approx 0.000053$.  These are small enough corrections that we can stay with the $11.4\%$ chance of winning.

Comment: I was working on an answer that was giving me the same estimate that you gave,but wasn't sure if I was correct or not, so (+1). However, not that it would make a difference here, but if one wanted to be exact, would you also need to consider the cases where there are $3$ rows / columns filled?

Comment: Yes, you would.  However, the chance of two is so small I am sure the chance of three would be really negligible.  You would have counted the $3$ line cases three times in the one line calculation, then subtracted them three times in the two line calculation, so should add them in once.  That comes from the inclusion-exclusion principle.